How to Obfuscate BuildConfig File Using ProGuard?
I am trying to implement code obfuscation using ProGuard in my Android project. While ProGuard successfully obfuscates other parts of the code, the BuildConfig file is still visible and readable when I decompile the APK.
I expected ProGuard to obfuscate the entire codebase, but the BuildConfig file retains its original form after decompilation, making sensitive information like version codes and build types easily accessible.
Here are the steps I’ve taken so far:
I configured ProGuard with a standard setup.
How can I ensure that the BuildConfig file is obfuscated or made non-readable when the APK is decompiled? Is there a specific rule I need to add to ProGuard or a different approach I should take?
Any guidance on how to fully obfuscate BuildConfig or prevent it from being decompiled would be much appreciated.
